# Why does my EC2 nameserver (correctly) resolve names to private IPs and then switches to public IPs?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bind

I'm running a nameserver for a few machines on EC2. This nameserver is not reachable via the public Internet. I want all my EC2 instances to use it to be able to find each other and to resolve all public domain names (e.g. `google.com`). Using CNAMEs I'm [supposed to be able to create my own names but defer to Amazon's internal EC2 nameserver for (internal) IP addresses](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal). It works for a while, but eventually some names incorrectly resolve to their *public* IP addresses.

Here's what is supposed to happen:

```
foo$ host bar
bar.tld is an alias for ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com has address 192.168.50.17
```

Here's what actually happens after a while:

```
foo$ host bar
bar.tld is an alias for ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com has address 88.88.88.88
```

Ack! If I restart BIND, it goes back to correctly resolving the name to the private IP for a while, then eventually serves the public IP. It never seems to revert to serving the private IP again unless I restart BIND.

By the way, this always seems to work:

```
foo$ host ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com 172.16.0.23
ec2-23-21-222-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com has address 192.168.50.17
```

If it seems like I don't know what I'm doing because I made a simple mistake in one of these config files, that's because I don't know what I'm doing.

I set up my own top-level domain: ".tld" (obfuscated--hopefully the real characters chosen for the top-level domain don't matter).

I tried to do [what Eric Hammond recommends](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal). Here's my `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";
  forwarders { 172.16.0.23; };
  auth-nxdomain no;
  listen-on-v6 { any; };
  allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.50.0/24; };
};
```

172.16.0.23 is the ip for Amazon's DNS server, only reachable from inside EC2. It is the only one that knows the correct internal/private IPs for my machines. It is almost as if my server is failing to resolve `foo.tld` sometimes, then goes off to some other [public] nameserver and the lookup is then borked (thereafter resolves to the public IP). The trick that I don't seem to be accomplishing is that my nameserver must *never* go beyond 172.16.0.23 to resolve these `x.compute-1.amazonaws.com` names. Another possibility is that sometimes Amazon's nameserver screws up and gives me a public IP, but then why would my nameserver not eventually correct the error and resolve the private IP again sometimes?

Anyway, moving on... here's `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "tld" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.tld";
  notify no;
};
```

For completeness sake, here's `/etc/bind/named.conf`:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

Here's my obfuscated bind database for my zone, `/etc/bind/db.tld`:

```
$TTL    1h
@       IN      SOA     tld. ns.tld. (
          2012021425         ; Serial
                  1m         ; Refresh
                  2m         ; Retry
                  1w         ; Expire
                  1h )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.tld.
@       IN      A       192.168.50.5
ns              A       192.168.50.5

foo     CNAME   ec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
bar     CNAME   ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

Whew. Ok, here are a couple more files that are probably necessary for the whole picture. Here's `/etc/resolv.conf` on the nameserver, `ns`:

```
domain tld
search tld
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Here's `/etc/resolv.conf` on `foo.tld` and `bar.tld`:

```
domain tld
search tld compute-1.internal
nameserver 192.168.50.5
nameserver 172.16.0.23
```

I don't know if that's correct. Maybe I should only have `nameserver 192.168.50.5`?

This setup uses BIND 9.7.3 on Ubuntu Server 11.10.

(FYI: cross-posted at http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal)

Comment: A couple of questions a) when your problem occurs, can you confirm that the wrong nameserver is being used: `dig host.tld | grep SERVER`; b) can you confirm that your resolv.conf is unchanged when the problem occurs? A lot of setups recreate this file on startup (and possibly at other times) using `/sbin/dhclient-script`. c) if neither of the above are true, can you confirm that you can manually reach the DNS server you setup, by explicitly specifying it with `dig @192.168.50.5 host.tld`

Comment: a) from `foo`, `dig bar.tld | grep SERVER` returns `;; SERVER: 192.168.50.5#53(192.168.50.5)`. b) resolv.conf files on ns and foo are unchanged (appear exactly as specified in my original post). c) confirmed: yes, I can manually reach my DNS server. The result of `dig +short @192.168.50.5 bar.tld` (from foo) is `ec2-88-88-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com (newline) 88.88.88.88`.

Comment: +1 For providing all the info. (worth +10 if only I could)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
options {
    forward only;
    ...
```

From BIND ARM97:

**forward** This option is only meaningful if the forwarders list is not empty. A value of `first`, **the
default**, causes the server to query the forwarders ﬁrst — and if that doesn’t answer the question,
the server will then look for the answer itself. If `only` is speciﬁed, the server will only query the forwarders.

In your case, as you actually need amazon DNS servers for .amazonaws.com only, you may also do:

```
options {
    forwarders { };
...
}

zone "amazonaws.com" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 172.16.0.23; };
    forward only;
};
```

Comment: Ok, right on. I'm testing this now. If this works for a day or so (that's how long it usually takes to start failing), the bounty is yours! Question: `only` seems counter-intuitive to me though... when I set `forward only`, why does my nameserver still resolve `ns`? I like that it does (it seems like `only` is what I need), I just don't understand it. Based on the BIND docs it seems like it actually shouldn't resolve `ns` (because it has to do that itself).

Comment: Guess amazon internal servers aren't just authoritative, they are also **recursive**.